# Microsoft teams bot getting members of a channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

in our use case, we have the team channel id with me. This is captured and stored into the DB in the event below

```
this.onTeamsChannelCreatedEvent(async (channelInfo: any, teamInfo: any, turnContext: any, next: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void> => {
}
```

We are running a periodic job and need to find out the members of a channel to perform some operations. So, how can i find members info from the channelid?

I have seen examples which using the context or context.activity. But in this case context wont be available. we are using nodejs v4.

My code here is

```
var client = new ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: channel.serviceUrl });

            client.fetchMembers(channel.serviceUrl, channel.channelId,
                (err, result) => {
                  if (err) {
                      functions.logger.log("failed to fetch team members")
                  }
                  else {
                    functions.logger.log("Team members are", result)
                  }
                }
              );
```

This now throws error

```
TypeError: client.fetchMembers is not a function
```

i have also tried client.fetchMembers but similar error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways you can do this:

1. Using the Microsoft Graph, in particular see the [List Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) operation.
2. By having a bot registered in the channel, which it sounds like you have already. You don't need an 'activity' at all, you can do this any time by accessing the Conversations object. In fact, this code doesn't even need to run in your "bot" project at all - as long as the bot is added to the team/channel, it will work to use the bot's credentials. You can see sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-context) in the Microsoft docs, and I have a sample from a recent conference session, doing this in dotnet from a console app over [here](https://github.com/HiltonGiesenow/TDO/blob/master/ProactiveConsoleApp/Program.cs#L43).

One thing that's worth noting, the members of a channel and the members of a Team are largely the same (only excluding Private channels), so that's why some of these options refer to the Team or Group.

Comment: i updated my code which is giving me trouble based on docs and your suggestion. please advise

Comment: I'm not super familiar with working with node for bots (I mostly use C# for this), but from what I can see, fetchMembers is on 'connector', not 'conversations' type

Comment: @Moblize, What trouble are you facing?

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT the trouble is that it errors out as fetchMembers is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [`teamsInfo.getTeamMembers()`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/f12710dffdd7cc09c97b4aa118f589e90910f536/libraries/botbuilder/src/teamsInfo.ts#L222) or [`teamsInfo.getPagedMembers()`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/f12710dffdd7cc09c97b4aa118f589e90910f536/libraries/botbuilder/src/teamsInfo.ts#L238) (if you want a paginated list), as in [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/8e8fed1f4f09932ff63cbdea8de70306b41dc424/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot/bots/teamsConversationBot.js#L170):

```js
    async getPagedMembers(context) {
        var continuationToken;
        var members = [];
        do {
            var pagedMembers = await TeamsInfo.getPagedMembers(context, 100, continuationToken);
            continuationToken = pagedMembers.continuationToken;
            members.push(...pagedMembers.members);
        } while (continuationToken !== undefined);
        return members;
    }
```

Comment: as i mentioned in my question,i do not have the context.  all i have is stored channel id, and service url that i got on onTeamsChannelCreatedEvent(async (channelInfo: any, teamInfo: any, turnContext: any, next: () => Promise<void>). i can persist teamsInfo object from channelCreated event if that is the right thing to do

Comment: Sorry. I missed that part. You'll need to generate the TurnContext object manually, then. After digging through the various private methods that get called, at a minimum, it's going to need: `context.adapter`, `context.activity.conversation`, `context.activity.channelData`,

Comment: And yes, I think you'll be able to use the one from `channelCreated`

Comment: so i can use teamsInfo from channelCreated then your  suggestions on comment above it are not needed. correct?

Comment: You should be able to, I think. I haven't tried it, but I believe that has all of the right information

Comment: ok so TeamsInfo.getTeamMembers still require turnContext. I have tried saving it into the db from channelCreated and using it. in that case it fails with error "client connector is required for this function". Then i trued to save activity and tried to create manually TurnContext using TurnContext(adapter, activity). in this case, i get a different error as "Error: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: Maybe instead of storing the turnContext, you should just get all the members at the `channelCreated` event. Then, you can store the members instead of the turnContext. You can always update it when the `onMembersAdded` method fires.

Comment: i was keeping that as a backup option as it always means me to do this house keeping. it would have been super simple to make a call when needed and get latest list of members in the channel.